# Why data retrieval failed with subreport Error with Microsoft ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a trouble with a report, but the strange thing it doesn't work only in production environment, if I deploy my solution on local IIS or in debugging stage with  VS2013 I can see the report with subreports populated properly.

I'm using VS2013 and ReportViewer2012.

So, In developing and test environment is all ok, but in production when I invoke the print occurs this "Data retrieval failed for the subreport ... (for all subreports) ".
Why?

So, I have a Report Container and within there are some subreports, and a bit code here:

**Source**

```
    loadDataSources(); //loading all datatables of subreports
    ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportContainer.rdlc");
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet0", _datatableContainer));
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

    CreatePDF(ReportViewer1, uniquefilename);


    void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ReportPath.ToLower() == "rpt_sub_1")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", _datatable1));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", _datatable2));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet3", _datatable3));
        }
        if (e.ReportPath.ToLower() == "rpt_sub_2")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet4", _datatable4));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet5", _datatable5));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet6", _datatable6));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet7", _datatable7));
        }
        //...
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this problem.

The problem was the value e.ReportPath.

It was in test and development environment as this: 
"rpt_sub_1" or "rpt_sub_2"

but in the production environment was different :
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\rpt_sub_1.rdlc" and "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\rpt_sub_2.rdlc"

I fixed creating an extension method as this:

```
    public static string CleanerReportName(this string value)
    {
        value = value.ToLower();
        List<string> _listRemoveItems = new List<string>();
        _listRemoveItems.Add(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\");
        _listRemoveItems.Add(".rdlc");
        _listRemoveItems.ForEach(x => value = value.Replace(x, ""));
        return value;
    }
```

and then I modified the source as following:

```
    void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ReportPath.CleanerReportName() == "rpt_sub_1")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", _datatable1));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", _datatable2));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet3", _datatable3));
        }
        if (e.ReportPath.CleanerReportName() == "rpt_sub_2")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet4", _datatable4));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet5", _datatable5));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet6", _datatable6));
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet7", _datatable7));
        }
        //...
```

I hope this post can help someone in the future.
Bye